# Reload Flask app when template file changes under Linux

Tags: python, linux, flask, jinja2

I am developing a flask application under Linux, and i'm suffering when i make any changes to template files.

Actually i well configured my app to reload on template changes using

```
TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True
```

**PS**: when i develop under Windows templates are reloading normally.

---

**EDIT**

I am using the built in server, and i run my app like this :

```
app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def run():
    """Run in local machine."""
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Here is my configuration class

```
 class DefaultConfig(object):
    # Project name
    PROJECT = "***"
    # Turns on debugging features in Flask
    DEBUG = True
    # secret key
    SECRET_KEY = "**************"
    # Configuration for the Flask-Bcrypt extension
    BCRYPT_LEVEL = 12
    # Application root directory
    APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # Application email
    MAIL_FROM_EMAIL = "**********"
    # Upload directory
    UPLOAD_DIR = "static/uploads/"
    # Avater upload directory
    UPLOAD_AVATAR_DIR = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, 'avatars/')
    ALLOWED_AVATAR_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
    # Instance folder path
    INSTANCE_FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join('/home/karim/OpenXC/Dashboard/Flask', 'instance')
    # Cache configuration
    CACHE_TYPE = 'null'
    CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60
    TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True
    # ToolbarExtention Configuration
    DEBUG_TB_ENABLED = False
    DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False
    DEBUG_TB_TEMPLATE_EDITOR_ENABLED = True
    DEBUG_TB_PROFILER_ENABLED = True
```

---

About cache i am using the cache extension by it's disabled. Please check the config file.

Thanks,

Comment: It does not work on some "unfriedly" file systems.

Comment: How are you deploying Flask? Does it happen with the builtin Flask development server? Also double-check that you're not viewing a cached version of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue by adding my template folder to extra_files parameter of Flask app

Here is how :

```
extra_dirs = [
    '/home/karim/flak_app/templates',
]

extra_files = extra_dirs[:]
for extra_dir in extra_dirs:
    for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(extra_dir):
        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                extra_files.append(filename)

app.run(threaded=True, extra_files=extra_files)
```

Hope this will help someone someday :)