# Setting up auto-refresh with Flask on template change

Tags: flask, web-development-server

I'm fairly new to programming so hopefully I convey this issue coherently enough. I've been setting up my developing enviroment for project - a web app using Flask - and for development, wanted to have my templates rendered every time I make changes to them without having to manually re-focus and refresh the browser. (hot-reload). I'm aware of --reload for flask, but this only restarts the server when changes are made to the app.py (in my case), not to .html templates. I have been trying multiple solutions for last 2 days and in the end I found a working solution of wrapping the flask (?) in Reloadium 1.3.0 package, which does exactly what I wanted. However of all the solution's I've tested prior, none of them worked or behaved as expected (most of the time didn't produce any result) and I stil have no idea why. I want to share some solution's I've checked and ask the question: **Why this didn't work?**. I'm using VSC and the Flask version is 3.0.0.

All those methods were tried on multiple browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome)

1. As per Flask's documentation on built in configuration values [TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/config/#TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD) should automatically enable in debug mode, so I've tried: `flask run --debug` but html templates weren't reloading on change and save. Only the server reloaded when changes were made to app.py, still requiring me to manually F5 the browser. So I tried explicitly stating in the program to enable TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD and run the app in python interpreter.
   `python app.py`

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True 
@app.route("/") 
def index(): 
    return render_template("index.html") 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```

but this still didn't work even if I ran the app in debug mode (by setting the argument): `app.run(debug=True)`

2. I've decided to try livereload 2.6.3 package by running the following code for flask (provided in livereload documentation), modified it because it seems that create_app() method is now depreciated from Flask 3.0.0.

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.debug = True 
server = Server(app.wsgi_app) 
server.serve()
```

Apparently this resulted in setting up livereload server(?) but when connecting to the main route, returned:
`TypeError: WSGIContainer.environ() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

3. I've tried solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063039/reload-flask-app-when-template-file-changes-under-linux), althou server is restarted with every template change, this change isn't reflected in the browser until I manually refresh the page.

Also I've tried multiple emalgamations and mixups of those methods but never I was able to get the code to at least behave partially to what would be expected. My only guess would be some version mis-match between livereload and Flask in the second solution, or issue with documentation for Flask 3.0 (however I doubt it) in solution 1. From what I understood from documentation, running Flask app in --debug mode would result in auto-reloading of the page in browser when changes are made to template. However I could not get this to work even closely to as expected.